# Set first radio button check and get value in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have 3 radio buttons and I was trying to set first radio button checked, I did it but I am not getting value with by default check first button. For that, I tried with `.trigger('change)` and `.click()` but didn't work.

Here is my screenshot of buttons:

[image]

If I click on it then I get value otherwise it's not giving his value.

Can someone tell me what's wrong I am doing?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.package_validity_child').each(function() {
    $("input[name='plan_name_selector']", this).get(0).checked = true;
  }).trigger('change');

  $('.plan_name').change(function() {
    var plan_name = $(".selected_plan_name").val();
    if (plan_name === 'Daily') {
      $('.days_names').css('display', 'none');
      $('.select_days').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      $('.days_names').css('display', 'block');
      $('.select_days').css('display', 'block');
    }
  });

  $("input[name='plan_name_selector']").click(function() {
    var value = $("input[name='plan_name_selector']:checked").val();
    $('.selected_plan_name').val(value);
    $('.selected_plan_nameVal').html("You have chosen <b>" + value + "</b> validity.");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="package_validity_child">
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" id="daily" name="plan_name_selector" value="Daily">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="daily">Daily</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" id="weekly" name="plan_name_selector" value="Weekly">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="weekly">Weekly</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" id="monthly" name="plan_name_selector" value="Monthly">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="monthly">Monthly</label>
  </div>
  <input type="" name="plan_name" class="form-control ml-4 mt-2 w-50 selected_plan_name" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above you should add function call after initial `checkbox` manipulation. I'd advise you to create a separate function and call it to do your stuff. Also, might be quite useful to have only one `change` handler to do all your needs, without an additional `click` handler too. And you should give a try to jQuery function [toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) which do the same functionality with `display: none/bock;` but in much easier way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.package_validity_child').each(function() {
    const $firstCb = $(this).find("input[name='plan_name_selector']").first();
    $firstCb.prop('checked', true);
    showValue($firstCb.val());
  });

  $('.plan_name').on('change', function() {
    const hideDays = $(this).val() !== 'Daily';
    $('.days_names').toggle(hideDays);
    $('.select_days').toggle(hideDays);

    showValue($(this).val());
  });

  function showValue(value) {
    $('.selected_plan_name').val(value).html("You have choosed <b>" + value + "</b> validity.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="package_validity_child">
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" id="daily" name="plan_name_selector" value="Daily">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="daily">Daily</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" id="weekly" name="plan_name_selector" value="Weekly">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="weekly">Weekly</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" id="monthly" name="plan_name_selector" value="Monthly">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="monthly">Monthly</label>
  </div>
  <input type="" name="plan_name" class="form-control ml-4 mt-2 w-50 selected_plan_name" />
</div>
```

Comment: Brother It's not hiding that 2 `div's`

Comment: I don't have your html to check. This is an example of how you can make your code much cleaner and readable. You can debug condition `hideDays` and understand why it's not working as designed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, what you want to do, but I think you want on page load to have "Daily" in your text input ? If this is correct you should add some logic on page load, not only on click:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var value = $("input[name='plan_name_selector']:checked").val();
    $('.selected_plan_name').val(value);
    $('.selected_plan_nameVal').html("You have choosed <b>" + value + "</b> validity.");

    if (value === 'Daily') {
        $('.days_names').css('display', 'none');
        $('.select_days').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('.days_names').css('display', 'block');
        $('.select_days').css('display', 'block');
    }

    $('.package_validity_child').each(function() {
        $("input[name='plan_name_selector']", this).get(0).checked = true;
    }).trigger('change');

    $('.plan_name').change(function() {
        var plan_name = $(".selected_plan_name").val();
        if (plan_name === 'Daily') {
            $('.days_names').css('display', 'none');
            $('.select_days').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $('.days_names').css('display', 'block');
            $('.select_days').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });

    $("input[name='plan_name_selector']").click(function() {
        var value = $("input[name='plan_name_selector']:checked").val();
        $('.selected_plan_name').val(value);
        $('.selected_plan_nameVal').html("You have choosed <b>" + value + "</b> validity.");
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="package_validity_child">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" id="daily" name="plan_name_selector" value="Daily" checked>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="daily">Daily</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" id="weekly" name="plan_name_selector" value="Weekly">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="weekly">Weekly</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input plan_name" id="monthly" name="plan_name_selector" value="Monthly">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="monthly">Monthly</label>
    </div>
    <input type="" name="plan_name" class="form-control ml-4 mt-2 w-50 selected_plan_name" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah but i also want that if `daily` is checked then my 2 `divs should be display: none` as i told in my code, you can see: `if(planname === 'Daily){}`

Comment: @ZainShabir It's edit, but NOTICE that in this variant you have code which is repeat, so you should add some functions.

Comment: Also NOTICE that I added checked to html code, so you should change it to works for you also :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use function to call in events. Please view example code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="plan_name_selector"]:first').attr("checked", true);
  check_plan_name_selector();

  $('.plan_name').change(function() {
    check_plan_name();
  });

  $("input[name='plan_name_selector']").click(function() {
    check_plan_name_selector();
  });

  function check_plan_name_selector()
  {
    var value = $("input[name='plan_name_selector']:checked").val();
    $('.selected_plan_name').val(value);
    $('.selected_plan_nameVal').html("You have choosed <b>" + value + "</b> validity.");
  }

  function  check_plan_name()
  {
    var plan_name = $(".selected_plan_name").val();
    if (plan_name === 'Daily') {
      $('.days_names').css('display', 'none');
      $('.select_days').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      $('.days_names').css('display', 'block');
      $('.select_days').css('display', 'block');
    }
  }

});
```